# Django -- can't import my own models

Tags: django, django-models, database-schema

I have several Django apps, all within one project directory. Each app has a `models.py` file with a bunch of models. I have been importing models from one app to the other with no problem, specifically to create a new model with a foreign key field, pointing to the model in the other app. No problem so far.

I decided to create a new model. It has 4 `ForeignKey` fields, each pointing to a different model in a different app. Straight forward. However, when I try to use `south` to migrate the schema to the database, it tells me that it can't import my models. Why?!

So, this is my new model:

```
class Action_Tracker(models.Model):
    dateOfAction = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Date of Action')
    user = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name = 'Action completed by')
    sys = models.ForeignKey(System, verbose_name='For System')
    wo = models.ForeignKey(Work_Order, verbose_name='Associated WO', blank=True, null=True)
    inv = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, verbose_name = 'Associated Invoice', blank=True, null=True)
    subdT = models.ForeignKey(SUBD_Tracker, verbose_name = 'Associated SUBD Tracker', blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(verbose_name='Notes of Action', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s -- %s' % (self.dateOfAction, self.notes)

    class Meta:
        orering = ['dateOfAction']
```

At the top of this `models.py` file I have the following imports:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm, forms
from staff.models import Employee, Position
from work_orders.models import Work_Order, SUBD_Tracker
from invoices.models import Invoice
```

From what I can tell, I *am* importing these correctly. However, when I try to do a schema migration, I get the following error:

```
File "/srv/www/cpm/../cpm/systems/models.py", line 4, in <module>
  from work_orders.models import Work_Order, SUBD_Tracker
File "/srv/www/cpm/work_orders/models.py", line 5, in <module>
  from systems.models import System
File "/srv/www/cpm/systems/models.py", line 4, in <module>
  from work_orders.models import Work_Order, SUBD_Tracker
ImportError: cannot import name Work_Order
```

Any idea what is going wrong here??

Thanks

**EDIT -- Upon Request**

I'm posting the work_order `models.py` code as requested (at least, the relevant parts):

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm, forms
from django import forms
from products.models import Product
from systems.models import System
from labour.models import Labour_Costs
from staff.models import Employee
from datetime import date
import datetime

class Work_Order(models.Model):
    IS_COMPLETE_CHOICES = (
        ('Y', 'Yes'),
        ('N', 'No'),
    )

    INVOICE_CREATED_CHOICES = (
        ('Y', 'Yes, mark WO complete and generate invoice (if applicable)'),
        ('N', 'No, just save these changes'),
    )

    WO_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Mechanical'),
        ('I', 'Install'),
        ('S', 'Show'),
        ('R', 'Service'),
        ('B', 'Blow down'),
        ('U', 'Start up'),
    )

    woID = models.CharField(max_length = 25, primary_key = True, verbose_name = 'Work Order ID')
    woType = models.CharField(max_length = 2, verbose_name = 'WO Type', default='R', choices = WO_TYPE_CHOICES)
    systemID = models.ForeignKey(System, verbose_name = 'System ID')
    notesToCrew = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = 'Notes to Crew')
    dateWOCreated = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True, default=datetime.date.today(), verbose_name = 'Date Created')
    dateWORequired = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = 'Date Required')
    dateCompleted = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = 'Date Completed')
    numDays = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 3, decimal_places = 0, verbose_name = 'Number of Days to Complete', blank = True, null = True)
    numHours = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 3, decimal_places = 2, verbose_name = 'Number of Hours to Complete', blank = True, null = True)
    isComplete = models.CharField (max_length = 3, default = 'N', verbose_name = 'Set WO as Completed?', choices = IS_COMPLETE_CHOICES)
    isScheduled = models.CharField (max_length = 3, default = 'N', verbose_name = 'Is WO scheduled?', choices = IS_COMPLETE_CHOICES)
    isReqSoon = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Is WO Required soon') #This flag will be set in a function to indicate that the WO is reqd within the current week/few days, whatever
    problemDescription = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Problem Description', blank = True, null = True)
    resolution = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Resolution', blank = True, null = True)
    serviceFromBD = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Service issues noticed', blank = True, null = True)
    serviceFromBDEstTime = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 3, decimal_places = 2, verbose_name = 'Est. Time to Repair', blank = True, null = True)
    numWorkers = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 3, default=1, decimal_places = 0, verbose_name = 'Number of Workers Required', blank = True, null = True)
    invoiceCreated = models.CharField (max_length = 3, default = 'N', verbose_name = 'Generate Invoice?', choices = INVOICE_CREATED_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.woID, self.systemID.systemAddress)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['woID']


class SUBD_Tracker(models.Model):
    SUBD_CHOICES = (
        ('U', 'Startup'),
        ('B', 'Blowdown'),
    )

    sys = models.ForeignKey(System, verbose_name = 'Related System')
    subd = models.CharField(max_length=1, verbose_name = 'SU or BD', choices = SUBD_CHOICES)
    ssn = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name = 'Season')
    approved = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = 'Approved', default = False)
    declined = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = 'Declined', default = False)
    cancelled = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = 'Cancel', default = False)
    firstNoticeSent = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = 'First Notice Sent?', default = False)
    secondNoticeSent = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = 'Second Notice Sent?', default = False)
    wo = models.ForeignKey(Work_Order, verbose_name = 'Related WO', blank = True, null = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.subd == 'U':
            return u'%s: Startup - %s' % (self.sys, self.ssn)
        else:
            return u'%s: Blowdown - %s' % (self.sys, self.ssn)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['sys']
```

Comment: Can you post the code of work_orders.models? This sounds like it could be something like a circular import.

Comment: That's precisely what I was thinking. I have been reviewing my code all afternoon and circular importing was starting to enter my thoughts. I will post the code...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read through the [ForeignKey documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey), you'll see that the first argument can be a string. This allows you to create your foreign keys without having to import, getting around the circular reference problem.

So your model would then become:

```
class Action_Tracker(models.Model):
    dateOfAction = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Date of Action')
    user = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name = 'Action completed by')
    sys = models.ForeignKey('systems.System', verbose_name='For System')
    wo = models.ForeignKey('work_orders.Work_Order', verbose_name='Associated WO', blank=True, null=True)
    inv = models.ForeignKey('invoices.Invoice', verbose_name = 'Associated Invoice', blank=True, null=True)
    subdT = models.ForeignKey('work_orders.SUBD_Tracker', verbose_name = 'Associated SUBD Tracker', blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(verbose_name='Notes of Action', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s -- %s' % (self.dateOfAction, self.notes)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['dateOfAction']
```

No import statements required!

Comment: OK that is fantastic. Thanks -- it worked like a charm. Plus, less crap at the top of my file. I might just go ahead and clean up all my other `models.py` files in the same manner.

Comment: but what if I want to import it not for declaring fields, but for simple use in some model methods (to do Objec get, select, creating and so on ?)

Comment: @user3479125 - simply import at runtime by putting the import statement inside the model method. This should be done rarely, as it is often a sign that your logic might be better placed in a view or form. Also, don't forget to use related managers - much better to use `post.comments.create(...)` than `Comment.objects.create(post=self, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks! post.comments.create a new thing for me, mayby in most cases, now I will work with related models without importing. (I don't think that it is good idea to put in views or form some code related to certian model and some models related with it).